# How to open gallery on default

Tags: android

I have an activity on my project.When a user comes to this activity,i want it to show the gallery with pictures by default.Without having to put a button to open the gallery.This activity should have the gallery open by default. I also cant find any tutorial about this. I've tried many ways but still it isn't working.How can i achieve this.

I want when a user comes to this activity,they should find the gallery open by default,without having to click a button to open it.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the **go to gallery button** programmatically when that activity is opening and by doing so it will go to the gallery without the user need to do anything :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ // you can call the button click inside on start as well
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout); 


    //please notice that it is important to check if your wanted permission was granted or not before performing this click
    galeryBtn.performClick()
}
```